# putImageData() draws scaled version of desired image to canvas, rather than 1:1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, image-manipulation

Seen here: A user draws an image using the color, freehand, and line-segment buttons. The 'edge-detect' button throws a red-bordered canvas over the original. The new canvas is supposed to overlay the original image with only it's red and alpha channel components. It does, only, the scale is warped.

here is the site

py.laymanindustries.com/ajaxthepicture.html

same-page source code

Comment: Please include the **relevant part** of the code inside the question itself. Have a look at [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I included the canvas, specified width/height, and toggled the display from 'none' to 'inline'. I was using jQuery to generate the canvas and I must've neglected to define the canvas properly.